# How to convert bytes to text and back to bytes?

Tags: python

I want to convert a picture into bytes and place it in a text file and then open that text file and convert it to a picture again.

```py
png=open("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\n.png","rb")
pngbytes=png.read()
newf=open("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\newf.txt","w")
newf.write(str(pngbytes))
newf.close()
newf=open("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\newf.txt","r")
newpng=open("C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\newpng.png","wb")
strNewf=newf.read()
newpng.write(strNewf.encode())
newpng.close()
png.close()
newf.close()
```

The image is created but can't be displayed.

Comment: What is the specific error you're receiving?

Comment: Please give your question a clearer title like "How to convert bytes to text and back to bytes?" or something like that. "Why can't I view the image?" is very vague and doesn't help anyone to find the question. Also, your question is only in the title, a clear title with the question in the text is less confusing.

Comment: There is no programming error, but the result is not the same as I want when I open the image that was created I see a message that the image can not be opened

Comment: It's not working because you're simply storing the string representation of the bytes, by using `str(pngbytes)`. What exactly would you expect to be in the text file and why would you want to do this in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your code to work by replacing `strNewf.encode()` with `eval(strNewf)`.

This works because the string you've created with `str(pngbytes)` gives you the string representation of the bytes, `eval` simply interprets that representation to give you the bytes again.

Why you'd want to do this is entirely unclear however - what are you trying to achieve? Because it seems that there's better ways to go about it...

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a full working example.

This will:
1) Load an image file into memory.
2) Convert the image into raw text.
3) Save the image as text into a different file.
4) Read the text file and convert it to the original image.

```
import base64

# Open image as bytes.
with open("8000_loss.png", "rb") as f:
    png_bytes = f.read()

# Convert bytes to text.
type(png_bytes)  # bytes
png_str = base64.b64encode(png_bytes).decode()
type(png_str)  # string

# Save text to file.
with open("wolverine.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(png_str)

# Read file as text.
with open("wolverine.txt", "r") as f:
    png_str2 = f.read()

# Convert text to bytes.
type(png_str2)  # string
png_bytes2 = base64.b64decode(png_str2.encode())
type(png_bytes2)  # bytes

# Validate the image has not been modified
assert png_bytes == png_bytes2
```

Answer (score 0):

you're not clear about the result of builtin-function 'str'